# How to change the prompt color?

Tags: linux, unix, command-prompt, csh

I'm writing the following line in `~/.cshrc`

```
set prompt="${green}${cwd} :- ${end} "
```

It sets the color to green but when I change the directory it automatically sets color to default.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some changes related to `cwd`, following should be used `%~`

You can check them [here](http://www.freebsdwiki.net/index.php/.cshrc)